# is there something like property observer in Dart?

Tags: dart

say I have a code like this

```
class MyClass {
  
  bool isLoading = false;
  String? errorMessage;
  
  void fetchData() {
    isLoading = true;
  }
  
}
```

as you can see in `fetchData` method, I set `isLoading` to be true.

what I want is....

whenever I set `isLoading` to be true then `errorMessage` property will automatically set to be null. so I don't have to manually assign null value to errorMessage property after I set `isLoading` to be true

```
// in a method
isLoading = true
errorMessage = null

// in another method
isLoading = true
errorMessage = null

// it is cumbersome to reassign error to be null over and over again after set isLoading to be true
isLoading = true
errorMessage = null
```

in Swift I can do it by using something called property observer

```
var errorMessage : String?
var isLoading: bool {
    didSet {
        if (isLoading == true) {
           errorMessage = null
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a getter and setter in Dart to intercept setting a value. There is no "didSet" interception, you have to do a full setter and actually set the value yourself.

```dart
class MyClass {
  // NOTICE: Don't set _isLoading directly, use [isLoading].
  bool _isLoading = false;
  String? errorMessage;
  
  void fetchData() {
    isLoading = true;
  }
  
  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;
  set isLoading(bool loading) {
    _isLoading = loading; 
    if (loading) errorMessage = null;
  }
}
```

That's not necessarily how I would design it, though.
Side effects on setters is a slightly iffy behavior that might surprise some people.

It'd probably instead have more precise method names for starting and stopping loading, ones which do not look like harmless assignments:

```dart
class MyClass {
  /// Whether we are currently loading.
  ///
  /// NOTICE: Do not set this variable directly, 
  /// use [startLoading] and [stopLoading] instead.
  bool _isLoading = false;
  
  String? errorMessage;
  
  void fetchData() {
    startLoading();
  }
  
  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;
  void startLoading() {
    _isLoading = true; 
    errorMessage = null;
  }
  void stopLoading() {
    _isLoading = false;
  }
}
```

This way, the only exposed way to set `isLoading` to true is to call `startLoading`.
You should never be assigning directly to `_isLoading`.
You can make `startLoading` and `stopLoading` private if you want to control when they get called.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Flutter, you could have a look at the [ValueNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) class. It easily allows you to add/remove listeners and trigger updates to them. It's quite handy to mimic the Observable pattern. Also (in the case of Flutter), you don't even need to rely on an additional package.